# url needs to include the InfoPath 2013 form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, sharepoint-server, infopath-rules

In a SharePoint 2013 workflow, I am currently sending out an email message that says we have received your list that you submitted. In that email message I want to give the user a url so they can click on the link and see the information that they added.

When the url is clicked, the link needs to include the InfoPath 2013 form along with the data that the user entered.

Would you tell me how to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Put a lookup in the body of the email with the [Encoded Absolute URL].

```
[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]?Openin=Browser
```

When selected, it will reopen the form in a web browser. This is good if you want to leave all fields editable.

If you create two form content types, let's say "New" and "Revisit", you could allow the form to be seen in two different ways:

- An open, editable form with all fields available for the user to fill out when they go to create a new form("New" Content Type).

Then once the form is submit, have the workflow change the content type to "Revisit" so

- User clicks the link to revisit their form information, it displays the form information and any other lookup information in a different form view.

Comment: The absolute encoded url does not work since the data is entered into an InfoPath 2013 form. Is there a way to have the custom list data displayed in an InfoPath form? if so, can you tell me how to accomplish this goal?